# Loading text files from the project

Tags: c#, file, text, loading

I'm using a text file in c# and i tried loading the file from the project itslef - i added it to the project but it didnt work. It only works when writing the full path of the file.
Anyone knows how to use the file in the project?
Thank you!

Comment: may be you are not copying that file to right, for e.g if you are working in debug mode then file should be in debug folder.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running your application in Visual Studio, then you could set the Copy to output directory flag of this file. This will copy the file at the same location as the executable. Then you could access it using a relative path:

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText("some_file.txt");
```

Also when deploying your application don't forget to include this file along with the executable.